# Where to find a solid Magento 2 SOAP-API Documentation

Tags: magento2, api, soap

I'm currently working on a webapp that communicates with a magento 2 server. I tried to use the soap interface for the communication but it quickly turned out, that the soap api changed from Magento 1 to 2. 
One difference i stumbled across, is that when i create a new category for example, i have to add the attribute `isActive` to the request. In the past, i used `is_active` but by using it, i always got an error, saying "`is_active`" is missing. After changing `is_active` to `isActive` it worked. 
My problems with this are:

1. I found out about the change by pure luck
2. The error message from magento was absolutely misleading

In the magento 2 devdocs i only found a solid documentation for the rest-api with all possible requests and what to send in the request body. I guess the soap api uses similar request bodies, but now i can't be sure anymore and don't want to get lost while programming due to lack of documentation.

So does anybody know where i can find a truly solid soap api overview for magento 2? All i can find is: How to get an auth-token and an list of the services and functions, but no documentation of the needed request body etc.

Comment: Any reason why you are going for soap instead of rest API?

Comment: Thank you! The previous system was working with magento 1.x and i would have liked it, if i could have reused as much code as possible. Because right now i am just porting old functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get get endpoint properties of a soap call by doing

```
https://[YOUR_MAGENTO_SITE]/soap/[COUNTRY_CODE]/?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1
```

Or

```
https://[YOUR_MAGENTO_SITE]/soap?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1
```

In the above case you will get all of the list of elements. `catalogCategoryRepositoryV1` is the a service name.

Have a look at [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/soap/bk-soap.html/) for more references.
Alternatively you can use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) for a better visual representation. You'll get something like this:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:gb="http://api-devmagento.endservices.info/gb/soap/gb?services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <gb:catalogCategoryRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
         <category>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <id>?</id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <parentId>?</parentId>
            <name>?</name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <isActive>?</isActive>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <position>?</position>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <level>?</level>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <children>?</children>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <createdAt>?</createdAt>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <updatedAt>?</updatedAt>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <path>?</path>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <availableSortBy>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>?</item>
            </availableSortBy>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <includeInMenu>?</includeInMenu>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <extensionAttributes/>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <customAttributes>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>
                  <attributeCode>?</attributeCode>
                  <value>?</value>
               </item>
            </customAttributes>
         </category>
         </gb:catalogCategoryRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
         </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me I am using SoapUi, and the Initial WSDL Url is not working there, given by you.

Comment: @Himani probably because it depends per site configuration. Your one will most likely be yoursite.com/soap?wsdl&services=catalogCategoryRepositoryV1